# Failed rails Heroku deploy on sprockets / jquery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

My initial deploy to Heroku for a Rails API app is being rejected with the following error:

`sprockets::filenotfound: couldn't find file 'jquery'`

My understanding with an API is that the asset pipeline should not have been included when the app was newed up (using the `--skip-sprockets`)? I asked the other devs that started the Rails side of this project if they recall initially passing that flag in but they don't, so not totally sure that would have resolved this.

Is there a way to run some form of that command after the fact? Can't seem to find anything.

- Tried manually removing the `public/assets` and sprockets manifest.

  - Only place anything jquery pops up with `grep -ri jquery`
- Made sure all `//require jquery` lines were gone from application.js.
- There are no views, so nothing in a header or footer is triggering it.
- Tried precompiling assets locally then pushing.

Just about all solutions for that message are for fixing it with jquery not without. Again, not 100% sure if I am right about not needing the pipeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up deleting the Heroku app and redeploying it after which it worked just fine. My guess would have been something was cached.